# Error in mail sending in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, gmail, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I am trying to send mail using my gmail account but its not working.

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

.env file
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=jitendrameena38@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

and mail.php is -

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => 'jitendrameena38@gmail.com', 'name' => "Minmarks"],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

and in my controller -

```
Mail::raw('This is an test e-mail', function ($message) {
                $message->to("jitu@gmail.com", "someone");
                $message->subject("hi checking");
                $message->getSwiftMessage();
            });
```

What is missing in this. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the port be 587?

Comment: i have used 465. But same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should set

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

It works for me.